# Pytest: Test user-edit view, object does not change

Tags: python, django, pytest

I want to test my account_edit view, if the user's/customer's info is being updated properply.
**I'm new to pytest.**

**View:**

```
@login_required
def account_edit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "account/user/edit_account.html", {"user_form": user_form})
```

**Factory:**

```
class CustomerFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        django_get_or_create = ("email",)

    email = "user1@gmail.com"
    name = "user1"
    mobile = "123456789"
    password = "user1"
    is_active = True
```

the **test_account_views.py**:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_account_edit_post(client, customer_factory):
    user = customer_factory.create()
    client.force_login(user)
    response = client.post(
        "/account/edit/",
        data={
            "name": "newname",
            "email": "newemail@gmail.com",
        },
    )
    print(user.name)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

When Im printing out the email *print(user.name)* Im expecting it to be updated with *newname*. However receiving the old one (user1) AND the response status is also OK: 200. So it seems the problem is just that the user isn't updating.
The problem is with testing code, not the django app itself(checked it).
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing user.name of user which you have already got from database. After it's changed in POST request you need to refresh it using `refresh_from_db()` method like that `user.refresh_from_db()` then print user.name